# In Access VBA on a Form I want to use two listboxes to sort and reorder a set of field names

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-access, listbox, filtering

I'm trying to create a filter so the user can choose any of 40+ fields to display in a query result that has been dynamically created via VBA.

This is something I see standard in a lot of programs so I figure someone must have code that does it without me reinventing the wheel.  Unfortunately I haven't been able to find it online.

Basically when it starts all the field names are listed in the left box and the right box is empty.  The user can click a right arrow button to move the fields into the right box or a left arrow to remove them and put them back in the left box.  Also the user can use up and down arrow buttons to change the order of a selected field in the right listbox.

Once I have the right listbox populated and ordered correctly I know how to execute the query properly.

Comment: you seem to have the basic idea nailed, so what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to find a full example for this then you'll need to work through it step-by-step yourself. Here is an [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223123%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for the `ListBox` control. There are links to the various methods and properties of this control at the bottom of the page.

Essentially, clicking a button (your arrow(s)) triggers the Click event;
In this event you might need to loop through to find the `Selected` item;
If the listbox is multi-select then you can examine the `ItemsSelected` collection;
Then you would use the `AddItem` and `RemoveItem` methods to move them for right-to-left or left-to-right.

I cannot recall currently whether the Field List option is *bound* to the table, or whether it just populates the list once when the form is loaded. If it is bound then you would instead need to use the Value List option and use VBA to retrieve all the field-names, and use these to set the `RowSource` (you may be doing this already).

In either event (Field or Value List) I don't believe the lists can remain sorted automatically (unlike in VB.NET). You will probably need to split the RowSource up into a (dynamic) array, find a simple sort routine to sort the array, and reassign the sorted items as the `RowSource`.

An alternative would be to create two temporary tables and use ADO (or DAO) to insert and delete rows between them, then use SELECT statements each time to re-populate the lists. This has the advantage that the SELECT can include an ORDER BY clause to sort the lists each time. However, It perhaps involves a little bit more effort (to maintain, and delete, the temporary tables).

You might, however, want to continue your search as I suspect an example is out there somewhere. Good luck.